Textbox returning empty value to backend
This is my frontend markup:
<p class="text-center" style="font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; font-size: 1.25rem; font-weight: bold;">
    Create an Account
</p>

<div class="mb-3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Username" CssClass="form-control" PlaceHolder="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_RegEmail" CssClass="form-control" PlaceHolder="Email Address" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_RegPassword" CssClass="form-control" PlaceHolder="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ConfirmPW" CssClass="form-control" PlaceHolder="Confirm Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="mb-3 text-center text-danger">
    <asp:CompareValidator
        ID="CompareValidatorPW"
        runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Passwords must match!"
        ControlToValidate="txt_ConfirmPW"
        ControlToCompare="txt_RegPassword"
        Operator="Equal"
        Type="String">
    </asp:CompareValidator>
    
</div>
    
<div class="d-grid">

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRegister" Text="Create Account" CssClass="Greengradiant btn- large" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  />
</div>

This is my backend code:
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Username: {txt_Username.Text}, Email: {txt_RegEmail.Text}, Password: {txt_RegPassword.Text}, Password2: {txt_ConfirmPW.Text}");

    Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString);
    
    conn.Open();
    
    bool exists = false;
    
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE Email = @email", conn))
    {
        //checks if the email that the user has entered exists in the database table
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", txt_RegEmail.Text);
        exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
    }
    
    // if the email exists, send an alert
    if (exists)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Sorry, Email is already taken!');</script>");
    }
    // else, insert 
    else
    {
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [USER] (User_ID, Username, Email, Password, Role, Created_At) " +
            "values (@id, @username, @email, @password, @role, @timestamp)";
    
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        string ePass = Hash.ComputeHash(txt_RegPassword.Text, "SHA512", null);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", ePass);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", newGUID.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_RegEmail.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txt_Username.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", 0);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", DateTime.Now);
    
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully created account! Welcome! ');</script>");
    }
    
    conn.Close();
    
    txt_Username.Text = "";
    txt_RegEmail.Text = "";
}

After clicking on the button, the values sent to backend such as txt_Username.Text is empty

Type of backend is ASP.NET Web Forms. The values that I receive in backend is empty, tested with the debug.writeline

Check the page load event. There is something there that clears the fields.

Your posted markup and code looks and works just fine.
This suggests that you have additional code on your page (code behind) that you are not sharing.
Remember, the page load event fires on EACH post back, and the page load event runs before your button code stub, and the page load event ALWAYS runs first.
So, if you have some setup code in the page load event (a common location for such setup code, say to clear out controls, or load up a dropdown list (combo box), then that code of course runs first. If the user is to say select a combo box value, you will find the user's combo box selection value gone!
Why?
Well, because your page load event fires each and every time, and if it loads up the combo box, then the user's choice will be lost.
So, what we need is a "first time" page load event (which we don't have).
However, this means to build a working webforms page, then for the last 200+ (or more) pages I have created, then you need to add/use/adopt a design pattern in which the page setup code runs only one time. You can achieve this goal by adding an If !PostBack code block.
Hence, near 99% of your webforms pages will have this code in the page load event:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // real first page load code goes here

            txt_RegEmail.Text = "";
            // more setup code goes here, load up some 
            // GridView or load up some combo boxes etc.

        }
            
    }

    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Username: {txt_Username.Text}, Email: {txt_RegEmail.Text}, Password: {txt_RegPassword.Text}, Password2: {txt_ConfirmPW.Text}");

    }

So, by adopting a code block with a !IsPostBack check, then you can have setup code and code in the page load event ONLY run on the first real page load, and thus such code will not run each and every time on say a button click. Hence, the fact that page load event fires and runs before the button click code stub will thus not matter (since it only ever runs on the true first page load).
So, keep in mind that any post-back (such as a button click) triggers the page load event each and every time, and THEN your button code stub code runs.
The other possible reason for control values being empty is if you have the posted markup nested inside of say a repeater, ListView, GridView etc., since in such cases, then multiple instances of the control can (will be) rendered, and thus direct use of the control name is not possible. (but then again, your code behind would not compile). So, if you nested your markup inside of one of these "data aware" controls, then you in near all cases have to get the given "instance" of the rendered row, and use findControl to get the correct instance of the given control. However, your posted markup (so far) shows no such nesting.
Also, I STRONG suggest that you adopt use of .Add() for SQL parameters, and not use AddWith, as this allows "strong" typing of the SQL parameters.  Also, you want to clean up your connection and SQL objects, hence this design pattern is recommended, and it saves you the trouble of having to ensure that the connection was closed after using.
You also have an error in your SQL. You have
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE Email = @email";

But your parameters used "email" and should use "@email".
eg:
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", txt_RegEmail.Text); <-- incorrect "Email"

Hence, try this pattern:
Debug.WriteLine($"Username: {txt_Username.Text}, Email: {txt_RegEmail.Text}, Password: {txt_RegPassword.Text}, Password2: {txt_ConfirmPW.Text}");

bool exists = false;
string strSQL =
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE Email = @email";


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =   txt_RegEmail.Text;
        exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
        if (exists)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sorry, Email is already taken!');</script>");
        }
        else 
        {
            strSQL = 
                @"INSERT INTO [USER] 
                (User_ID, Username, Email, Password, Role, Created_At)
                values (@id, @username, @email, @password, @role, @timestamp)";

            cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            string ePass = Hash ComputeHash(txt_RegPassword.Text, "SHA512", null);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  ePass;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_RegEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_Username.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@role", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  0;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@timestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully created account! Welcome! ');</script>");
        }
    }
}
txt_Username.Text = "";
txt_RegEmail.Text = "";

